# Strange button tag in bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found this button tag in the basic bootstrap html [template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/#) (I added the arrows)

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
  --> <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  --> </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
```

It's completely invisible (at least to me), and it doesn't seem to have any effect (it doesn't happen anything when I click).

Is it supposed to be like this, and what's the point of it?

Answer (score 3):

**Where is the button:** That button can be seen when you reduce the webpage width, either by zooming in or using a mobile device to access the webpage.

**What is this button for:** That button is use to toggle the navbar dropdown on mobile devices.

Those three lines stacked on top of each other is the button:

[image]

Comment: Might be worth just mentioning that the spans are the lines on the button 

Answer (score 1):

It's the menu toggle for small displays like smartphones. On big screen it will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the above answers.

In order for the button to have a working functionality, you need to load jquery library and right after it the bootstrap jquery library. 
These can be included either in the head tag of your html code or just before the end of the body tag (2nd option is best practice).
Try it like this (cdn used):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```